# How to change the location where the gerrit hooks are running from?

Tags: gerrit, githooks, gerrit-trigger

I am running into a problem where my gerrit hooks are being triggered from a different directory,
I have os.getcwd() as the first line in my change-merged hook,it shows as `/mnt/data1/STORE/git/project.git` depending on the project the hook is triggered from, I want the hook to run from `/gerrit_v2/hooks` ,how to make this change?where to look for?is there a place to check the hook logs on how it is being triggered?please advise

FYI..I am using gerrit `2.14`

Answer (score 0):

You can't change that. Hooks are executed from the root of the repository which triggered them. If you want, you can change the current directory using the "chdir" command.